Youtube API issue, ONLY VIDEO
I need your advice. Currently, I have an app that integrates with an API that returns video qualities from 144p to 360p, but the problem is that only one quality has sound, and the others only have video. The client is in a hurry and wants the app, and I'm not sure what to do. I’ve searched a lot and tried to play video and audio together, but the sound leads the video, so they are not synchronized. What advice do you have for this issue?

Add thecode you're using
